# Development provisioning profile and Team provisioning profile

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, apple-developer

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html):

> Because Xcode creates and manages team provisioning profiles for you, you only create a development provisioning profile **if you want to restrict development of an app to specific team members and devices**.

If I'm not mistaken the *team provisioning profile* contains all certificates and devices for the entire team *and* is automatically available to all team members.

assuming the above is correct, how does creating a *development provisioning profile* "restrict development of an app to specific team members and devices"

Answer (score 0):

The development provisioning profile that you can create **on the developer portal** allows you to select specific users (there's checkboxes there), as well as you can select which devices will be allowed to be used (again, checkboxes).

It restricts development by not allowing the entitlements associated with the app's bundle id to be used outside of the specified users/devices.

Of course anyone could just change the app bundle id inside xcode, but then it would behave as if it was a new app with a different name, and also it wouldn't have access to important resources such as push notifications, game center, icloud, etc that you had specified in the developer portal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @pochi. Follow up: If a team member's certificate and devices are **not** included in a newly created *development provisioning profile*, wouldn't the team member be able to "bypass" the restriction by building using the *team development profile* which **does** include his certificate and devices.

Comment: Kind of, like you can't stop people from running your code if thats what you mean. You can stop them from using a specific profile along with anything associated with it. So people CAN build it but they can't Archive/Export or do any other meaningful actions. This is possible since you have to create a specific provisioning profile (NOT a wildcard) when using special entitlements. But Xcode will still try to match it. So thats why if anyone wants to build your app all they have to do is change the bundle identifier.

Comment: According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile.html): _"The team provisioning profile allows all your apps to be signed and run by all team members on all your team’s devices."_. This is equivalent to a development provisioning profile created manually on the developer portal with all certificates and devices checked right?

Comment: and on the same page: "_if you enable an app service that requires an explicit App ID, Xcode creates and uses an explicit App ID in a new team provisioning profile it also creates._". Is the following statement correct: **every** team member **always** has access to every single _team provisioning profiles_ (One profile per explicit appID).

Comment: I guess I'm not really understanding who we're trying to restrict, what we're trying to restrict them from doing, and why we're trying to restrict them.

Comment: What would be a reason to create a custom development provisioning profile? Would it be for testing purposes or for security reasons?